# Connect 2 monitors to Macbook Pro 2012

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, displayport

I own a 2012 Macbook Pro with Core i7, 1GB Nvidia Graphics, 8GB RAM and 1 TB HDD. I want to connect 2 external monitors to it using the thunderbolt port because thats the only port I have. It doesn't have HDMI or VGA port.

Right now I have one external monitor connected using thunderbolt to dvi adapter. I was wondering if its possible. I have another VGA monitor that I wish to connect. But I am not sure how to do so, there are some accessories available which are too expensive.

I came across this product which is a thunderbolt to HDMI/DVI/VGA (3 in 1) adapter. 
I was wondering if it would be able to support two monitors at once.

[http://www.amazon.com/VicTec-DisplayPort-Thunderbolt-Adapter-ThinkPad/dp/B00K43Q8BS/ref=sr_1_10?ie=UTF8&qid=1422420455&sr=8-10&keywords=thunderbolt+to+dvi+vga+hdmi](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K43Q8BS)

Answer (score 4):

No, that 3-in-1 adapter will not drive multiple monitors.

What you need is either a system that combines 2 monitors, or a system that chains them. While DisplayPort allows for daisy-chaining displays, this only works on supported hardware. This means your monitors need to both have two DisplayPort connectors and official support from the vendor and inside in the chipset to make this work.

I believe that you aren't going to buy two expensive chain-able monitors since, well, you don't want to buy an expensive adapter ;-) The next stop would be stuff like Matrox's DualHead2Go. That is a device that allows 2 displays to be connected to a computer as one big display. http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital_se/
It does cost quite some money, so it might be in your category of 'expensive adapters'...

The problem with your question is that it is rather specific. It's a niche that most people don't even know about, and not a lot of sales or development is happening there. While it could probably be done cheaper, there simply aren't a lot of options here.

Just remember: one video port can only ever drive 1 display, unless it's a daisy chained display port system or a device that turns 2 screens into 1 big virtual screen for the video port. There is no cheap 2-in-1 adapter to make this happen.

Small addition: you might be able to solve your problem with a USB DisplayLink adapter if you do not need 3D video or accelerated 2D video. It's a video card with a USB connector on one end and a video port on the other. It won't be fast or high-performance, but if you simply want more desktop space, it might work for you. You would end up with one of these: http://www.displaylink.com/shop/adapters

Comment: I have the same exact problem as the OP. I have a Macbook Pro with only one video port - a DisplayPort, and I want to connect the laptop to two external monitors...

Comment: Well, this applies to you too

Comment: yep seems like displaylink is the way to go, I have heard that from multiple sources now, thanks

Comment: Yeah, but with USB, remember that your resolution and video acceleration will not be as good as your built in GPU.

Comment: yeah thanks - one more question for you - I want a displaylink device that works with both windows and mac - is that possible? same device, that is  usb / hdmi for both, but one case the laptop is a lenovo, the other its a macbook

Comment: Yes, that will work. You just need to install the drivers on both systems, and the adapter will work fine.

Comment: DisplayLink has drivers for Catalina.  I use a Lenovo USB-C Dock for work, which also works with my Macbook with that driver.

Answer (score 1):

Also in the category of "expensive solutions" falls this: Your MacBook Pro 2012 can drive two Thunderbolt Displays. You can buy the displays at [Apple's store](http://www.apple.com/displays/). The information on how many Thunderbolt displays are supported on any given Mac can be found in the [Thunderbolt FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219).

Answer (score 0):

I have read somewhere on the apple site that the Macbook Pro 2012 mid graphics card IS capable of running dual monitors. It however does not say HOW to do this just that it is capable.

So in my opinion having the suggested link https://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital_me/#close enables 2 moniters and then using the USB 3.0 and a graphics card apater you could possibly hook up another 2 screens.

I would really love a Hub that could do it all but I just can not see any.